# wireguard android library - Error UAPIOpen: ... permission denied

Tags: android, wireguard

I'm trying to make android WireGuard client using com.wireguard.android:tunnel library.

- Client platform: Android
- Library: com.wireguard.android:tunnel (1.0.20211029)
- My app package name: com.example.hellowireguard
- Test devices: Nexus 5X
- WireGuard server: ubuntu 20.04

When trying to connect, I got this error.
But, the connection appears to be working fine.

> E/WireGuard/GoBackend/abc: UAPIOpen: mkdir /data/data/com.wireguard.android: permission denied

Can this error be ignored?

[image]

Comment: It's totally fine imho